# Gitlab projects disappeared, can't push to repo anymore

Tags: git, gitlab

I have some projects in my gitlab.

I did try to push to it and got:

```
Access denied.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't see the projects on Gitlab anymore. The git repositories still exist in /home/git/repositories

Comment: It clearly says that u dont have access to that repo? Have you push to that repo before?or is this your first time?

Comment: I ever pushed to the repo

Comment: What do the logs say? Have you changed something on the setup?

Comment: I did not deleted the project nor change settings. I need to investigate cause it is like the DB has rolled back.

Comment: I did recreate the repo vie Gitlab. Gitlab did not recreate git repo. I am able to push again.